# How to create onpopstate event on click back and forward button

Tags: jquery, ajax, history

I have created a jquery ajax code to display a content using **pushstate**, it works good but when I click on back and forward button the content doesn't change again. How to create event **onpopstate** in this case ?

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".load-ajax").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var route = $(this).attr('href');

            $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: Routing.generate('admin_order_state_new'),
                success: function (msg) {
                    if (msg["ok"] === undefined) {
                        alert('error');
                    } else {
                        window.history.pushState(null, "Title", route);

                        $("#mydiv").html(msg["ok"]);
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved

```
$(document).ready(function () {

function loadPage(route) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'html',
        url: route,
        success: function (msg) {
            if (msg === undefined) {
                alert('error');
            } else {
                $('#content').replaceWith(
                    // with the returned one from the AJAX response.
                    $(msg).find('#content')
                );

            }
        }
    });
}

$(window).on('popstate', function () {
    loadPage(location.pathname);
});

$(".load-ajax").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var route = $(this).attr('href');

    window.history.pushState(null, "Title", route);

    loadPage(route)

 });


});
```